# Wrong device count after connecting a new device

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

I'm integrating Agora with Unity, and we have a device selection screen for the user to select and test their devices before joining a call.
The problem I'm having is that Agora is not detecting device changes accordingly in runtime, which won't let me update my UI to reflect these changes.

```
void Start()
{
    // get Agora engine, should be initialized already in the AgoraIOController component
    agoraEngine = GetComponent<AgoraIOController>().GetAgoraEngine();
    agoraEngine.OnAudioDeviceStateChanged += DeviceChangedHandler;
    InitializeDeviceManager();
}

...

void DeviceChangedHandler(string deviceId, int deviceType, int deviceState)
{
    devicesDirty = true;
    onDevicesChanged.Invoke();
}

...

void RefreshDeviceList()
{
    devices.Clear();

    int audioDeviceCount = audioDeviceManager.GetAudioPlaybackDeviceCount();
    if (audioDeviceCount == (int)ERROR_CODE.ERROR_NOT_INIT_ENGINE)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Agora engine not initialized, can't refresh devices");
        return;
    }
    else if (audioDeviceCount < (int)ERROR_CODE.ERROR_OK)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"Unknown error while trying to get devices. Error code: {audioDeviceCount}");
        return;
    }

    Debug.Log($"Found {audioDeviceCount} audio devices.");

    for (int i = 0; i < audioDeviceCount; i++)
    {
        string deviceName = null;
        string deviceId = null;
        int result = audioDeviceManager.GetAudioPlaybackDevice(i, ref deviceName, ref deviceId);
        if (result != (int)ERROR_CODE.ERROR_OK)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Error when trying to get audio device");
            continue;
        }

        devices.Add(new AgoraDevice()
        {
            deviceId = deviceId,
            deviceName = deviceName,
            type = MEDIA_DEVICE_TYPE.AUDIO_RECORDING_DEVICE
        });
    }

}
```

If I connect a new microphone and restart the application, it's detected as expected, but if I connect a new device in runtime, I get the event for `agoraEngine.OnAudioDeviceStateChanged` but when I refresh the device list, the device count and device info is not being updated, so my UI is not showing the new state accordingly.

This happens if I have one mic and I connect a second one, or if I have two mics and I disconnect one. In either case Agora is not reflecting these changes after the devices changed event.
I also tried refreshing the device list in the next frame, or adding a button to manually refresh the list, to check if there was some delay in Agora for doing that update, but it's not happening.
Without this feature we're gonna have lots of issues with clients, connecting new devices in runtime happens all the time and we need to make this software robust and support these scenarios.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

Releasing and recreating the device manager helped, and the device list is updated, but this looks really weird and I don't think that the API should be used like this.

```
void DeviceChangedHandler(string deviceId, int deviceType, int deviceState)
{
    devicesDirty = true;
    audioDeviceManager.ReleaseAAudioRecordingDeviceManager();
    audioDeviceManager.CreateAAudioRecordingDeviceManager();
    onDevicesChanged.Invoke();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are testing with mic plug/unplug, did you intend to call AudioPlaybackDeviceManager instead of AudioRecordingDeviceManager in your first part of the code?